# How can one move a group of objects?

Tags: python, object, graphics

I am currently using [graphics.py](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html) and I am trying to figure out how to move a bunch lines together. The program I wrote draws a grid of lines, and  I  am unsure how I would write something that would move the entire grid by 1,1 every X seconds for Y seconds. Is there a way to merge all of the lines together? Or, how would one go about doing this?

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("Thing",500,500)
win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
a = 0
slength = 1
while True:
    a = a + slength
    vgrid = Line(Point(a,0),Point(a,500))
    hgrid = Line(Point(0,a),Point(500,a))
    vgrid.draw(win)
    hgrid.draw(win)
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about linear transformations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing them in a class, then accessing their positions together. Keep in mind I know nothing of the graphics.py library, but you should be able to do something like `Line.Point1 = Point(b, c)`. Then you should be able to do:

```
win = GraphWin("Thing",500,500)
win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)

class MyDrawing:

    def __init__(self):

        self.horizontals = []
        self.verticals = []
        a = 0
        slength = 1

        while True:
            a = a + slength
            self.verticals.append(Line(Point(a,0),Point(a,500)))
            self.horizontals.append(hgrid = Line(Point(0,a),Point(500,a)))
        for line in self.verticals:
            line.draw(win)
        for line in self.horizontals:
            line.draw(win)

    def move(self, x, y):

        for line in self.verticals:
            line.Point1 = Point(line.Point1.x + x, line.Point1.y + y)
            line.Point2 = Point(line.Point2.x + x, line.Point2.y + y)
        for line in self.horizontals:
            line.Point1 = Point(line.Point1.x + x, line.Point1.y + y)
            line.Point2 = Point(line.Point2.x + x, line.Point2.y + y)
```

Comment: But I would also suggest a library that was built for higher level graphics programming (this one doesn't seem to be - graphics sounds about as low as you can go on higher-level programming). You should check out pygame and Kivy!